# Is there a function equivalent to WHEN in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

For example: I have a page that lists book titles stored in a database. What I want to happen is `WHEN` it gets to a certain book title say something different or add additional info like "ON SALE".

Is there a function that exists that allows me to manipulate data inside a loop?

I've tried a couple of things, but have not gotten the desired results.

Here's my thought process:

Query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM   `artist`
            ORDER BY artist_name ASC";

    $q = $db->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Output:

```
 <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()); ?>
                                <li class="<?php echo $r['sort_status']; ?>">
                                    <figure>
                                        <div class="gallery-img"><a href="book/<?php echo $r['book_slug']; ?>/<?php echo $r['book_id']; ?>"><img src="books/<?php echo $r['photo']; ?>" alt="picture of <?php echo $r['book_title']; ?>"></a></div>
                                        <figcaption>

                                            <h3 class="padding-fifteen-bottom"><?php $book = $r['book_title']; if($book=="A Tale of Two Cities"){echo "A Tale of Two Cities - On Sale NOW! ";} else { echo htmlspecialchars_decode(truncate($book,34));}?></h3>

                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </li>
                                <!-- end work item -->
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes!

```
if($book_title == "My Title") 
{
   // Logic here.
}
```

HTML format

```
<?php if($book_title == "My Title"): ?>
<p>my html</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm having trouble understanding the concept.  Do I need to format the entire HTML each time within the end if statement or can I simply echo the response I want?

Comment: Yes you can simply echo out the response you want. The second example is just a way of giving html response without having to put it within a echo or print.

Comment: I'm now getting a series of duplicates from the if statements. For example: `A Tale of Two Cities` becomes `A Tale of Two Cities A Tale of Two Cites - On Sale Now` below is what my code now looks like: `<?php 
$book = $r['book_title']; 
if ($book == "a tale of two cities") { echo "A Tale of Two Cities - On Sale Now!"; }
if ($book == "2 Live and Die in LA") { echo "2 Live in Die in LA - One Sale Noe "; } else echo {echo htmlspecialchars_decode(truncate($book,34));}
                                                ?>`

Comment: Yes because your else statement is malformed. Use this <?php 
$book = $r['book_title']; 
if ($book == "a tale of two cities")
{ 
echo "A Tale of Two Cities - On Sale Now!"; 
} 
if ($book == "2 Live and Die in LA") 
{ 
echo "2 Live in Die in LA - One Sale Noe ";
} 
else 
{
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(truncate($book,34));
} 
?>

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I'm still getting duplicates. I guess I'll have to find another way of doing. I'll mark your answer a correct, because your answer is in harmony with my original thought process. So I'm guessing the issue is either from my DB or elsewhere in the code on my page. Thanks again.